# Flask API authorization without "login"

Tags: python, flask

I see a lot of examples online showing how to add authentication to a flask API using JSON Web Tokens which requires a login. For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5bIPtEbS0Q

How can I add authentication without having to actually "login"? I have a public flask API that is hosted with AWS App Runner. The API is triggered whenever a user sends a SMS message to a number, then the API is called via an internal AWS Lambda function. You can see the architecture in the image below. We are also going to expose this API on our website to allow people to ask questions there, which I believe means the API URL will be exposed with the requests.

```
@app.route("/api/text_bot", methods=["GET"])
def text_bot():
    # code
    return jsonify(response)
```

How can I ensure that the request authorization headers have a valid token when the API is called?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think you should create a decorate function to check authorization header before pass to api

Example:

**Authority.py**

```
from functools import wraps 
from flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators 
import _decode_jwt_from_request 
from flask import request


def decode_jwt():
    # replace your logic vaild data here
    # ex: auth_header = request.headers.get("authorization")
    # now: you can use this jwt to check valid
    # here is a sample use flask_jwt_extended
    jwt_data = _decode_jwt_from_request(locations="headers", fresh=False)
    return jwt_data


def jwt_required(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        jwt_data = decode_jwt()
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

API.py

```
@app.route("/api/text_bot", methods=["GET"])
@Authority.jwt_required
def text_bot():
    # code
    return jsonify(response)
```

Comment: what value am i passing to the authorization header to decode?

Comment: with param `locations="headers" `, it 'll trigger to field `Authorization` in request headers.Others, you can use `request.headers.get("authorization")` to get custom value from header that you want

Comment: value can a jwt bearer token or simple a serect api key